# Git Install Mac Stuck Verification

Tags: git, macos, verification

When I open the .pkg file I downloaded from git, to install git on my machine I'm stuck on this screen[image]

Any idea how to force this verification/bypass? I already have XCode and the Command Line Tools installed.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210642/pkg-for-installer-hangs-on-verify for a related problem.

Comment: nice...I'm hoping that upgrading from 10.11.4 to 10.11.5 will fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's a bug with 10.11.4, upgrading to 10.11.5 fixed the issue :)

Comment: I have the same problem (although with Virtualbox instead of git) and I'm already running 10.11.5 :-|

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think off the top of my head is system preferences like security or browser. I have a mac also and I used to try to download some things and it wouldnt let me until I set I think my browser preferences to allow anything.

Comment: You said you got it new. Have you set a password for your user yet?

Comment: Did you read forum that mattias sent you? Cause that sounds good and I cant really think of anything else usually all that I told you works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had (what I assume is) the same problem, although with VirtualBox instead of git.  As suggested [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=77122), I ran `/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app` explicitly, and "pointed it" at the .pkg file on the mounted dmg; that worked fine.

Comment: This is exactly what is stated in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210642/pkg-for-installer-hangs-on-verify